# Treatment of waiting time data with repeated observations for a finite time

Tags: survival, censoring, queueing, interarrival-time

A call center is open for 9 hours every day. My data are the times of occurrence of calls, divided in days. Some days are busier than the others and some days no calls at all occur. I have to estimate the distribution of the waiting times. The questions are:

1. How can I deal with the data of those days when no calls occur?
2. At the end of a working day, the center closes. How to treat the data that no calls occurred between the last call and the closing time?

Is it reasonable to just neglect those data or to consider the working days as continuous (in this way I sum up the "residual" waiting time from one working day to the waiting time for the first call of the day after)?

Comment: The problem you are referring to is called *censoring*. I added the tag.

Comment: Thanks gung, I started to read something about censoring and it looks promising...